# How can I stop overlapping textboxes when I add new line to the current textbox on Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am trying to edit a PDF book on Adobe Acrobat. When I add the new line to the textbox, my current textbox is overlapping with next textbox instead of making the next textbox shifting down. Here is an example that explains my situation:

[image]

How can I fix that?

- Currently, I am using method 3 to edit PDF but I am open to new advice.

***Method 1 :*** Converting PDF to the other text-based formats

Converting it other formats causes a lot of data and font loss. I need a trick to shift all textboxes down on adobe acrobat.

***Method 2 :*** Shifting all elements of the PDF down

I need to shift the textboxes of the book little bit down so I can add something new to the textbox but I don't know how can I achieve that?

***Method 3 :*** Increasing the sizes of pages

Increasing the sizes of pages from Tools>Set Page Boxes seems useful workaround for me. This allows me to shift the text boxes of the page down. So I can add my text easily.

Comment: I can think of two possible solutions. Either copy all the texts and paste it into a new textbox (but loose formating) or move the other textboxes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround is increasing the size of pages. Increasing the size of pages from Tools>Set Page Boxes seems useful workaround for me. This allows me to shift the text boxes of the page down. So I can add my text easily.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Although it has some tools to make some content adjustments Adobe Acrobat is not a text editing program.

You should use a suitable application for this type of work such as InDesign, edit the original file and export a new PDF.

Or open the PDF in Adobe Illustrator and try to solve it. But in a book I see it something difficult.

Comment: Thank you. But if it is not a text editing program why it is called a PDF editing program? I want to edit the text and expand the content of the book. I have tried to convert it to the word and HTML file and it lost a lot of content. Also, I cannot open PDF files with Adobe InDesign.(I am wondering how that static primitive uneditable format become industry standard.)

Comment: @my-lord Acrobat is an editor for "touch ups" - change a word here or there, alter a color, swap an image etc. It's *never* been meant as a full fledged layout editor. Acrobat is first and foremost a tool for *output and distribution* - that is where it is "industry standard". Editing is secondary. Ideally you would have any "book" in a native application such as InDesign or QuarkXpress. You would use *that* application to make layout alterations and then *regenerate* a PDF for output and distribution.