# How can I select all elements until reaching the end of the pdf on editing mode?

Tags: selections, adobe-acrobat

I want to select all elements until reaching the end of the PDF on editing mode. For example, let say I have a 290 pages book and I am on page 83. How can I select all elements until reaching the end of the PDF?

The method that I tried is selecting an area and pressing the End key to go to the end of the PDF on selection mode but this method didn't work as I expected.

Comment: If you want to select all the objects from the page 83 until the end it's not enough selecting just the pages from the page 83 until the end?

Comment: Thanks. I can select pages on View > Navigation Panels > Pages but that selection doesn't allow me to select items like this:https://streamable.com/gjrf4

Comment: But if you could select all the items of several pages, do you think afterwards you can move them all at the same time? It's impossible in Acrobat, not in InDesign either. It's just something you can do in Illustrator by selecting all the items in various artboards. As you have been answered in [other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/121678/120647), you want to do text editing work and manipulating objects in a program that is not intended for that. You must use a vector application that allows you to edit PDF pages like Illustrator, make the modifications & create a new PDF